# JavaScript class extends with onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I face a problem with ajax on onclick function. 
In html

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="metro" placeholder="Area">
  <div id="areastatus"></div>
</div>
<div class="boo">
  <ul>
    <li>KHULNA</li>
    <li>KUSHTIA</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="keyword" placeholder="Area">
  <div id="keystatus"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In javascript

```
$(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('#metro').val($(this).text());
  $('#areastatus').fadeOut();
});
$(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('#keyword').val($(this).text());
  $('#keystatus').fadeOut();
});
```

Here when any li is clicked then those are fadeout and send same text value in text field. I need to identify whose li is clicked 'boo' or 'foo' and send the particular value in text field.
please help me out..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the colsest parent and then use `.attr("class")` to get the class name like

```js
$("li").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).closest("div").attr("class"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <input type="text" id="metro" placeholder="Area"> 
 <div id="areastatus"></div>
</div>

<div class="boo">
 <ul>
  <li>KHULNA</li>
  <li>KUSHTIA</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="text" id="keyword" placeholder="Area"> 
 <div id="keystatus"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
 <ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code example you can put to get the class name for list item which is clicked

```js
$(document).on('click','li',function(){
                    
            alert($(this).parent().parent().prop('class'));
            $('#metro').val($(this).text());
            $('#areastatus').fadeOut();
        });
$(document).on('click','li',function(){

            alert($(this).parent().parent().prop('class'));
            $('#keyword').val($(this).text());
            $('#keystatus').fadeOut();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <input type="text" id="metro" placeholder="Area"> 
 <div id="areastatus"></div>
</div>

<div class="boo">
 <ul>
  <li>KHULNA</li>
  <li>KUSHTIA</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="text" id="keyword" placeholder="Area"> 
 <div id="keystatus"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
 <ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Try this in both the functions:

```
 $(document).on('click','li',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().prop('class');
        $('#metro').val($(this).text());
        $('#areastatus').fadeOut();
    });
```